# ValidationError: Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. react

Tags: reactjs, sass, source-maps, webpack-style-loader, validationerror

I'm using react, my project was running just fine, then out of nowhere i got this error with all the sass file

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'sourceMap'. These properties are valid:
   object { injectType?, attributes?, insert?, base?, esModule?, styleTagTransform? }
    at validate (D:\projects\react\template2\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:191:11)
    at Object.getOptions (D:\projects\react\template2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:591:19)
    at Object.pitch (D:\projects\react\template2\node_modules\style-loader\dist\index.js:22:24)
```

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.22000
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 5.85 GB / 15.85 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 19.7.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 9.5.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: Spartan (44.22000.120.0), Chromium (116.0.1938.69)
    Internet Explorer: 11.0.22000.120
  Packages:
    sass-loader: ^10.0.0 => 10.0.0 
    style-loader: ^3.3.3 => 3.3.3 
    webpack: ^5.88.2 => 5.88.2 
    webpack-cli: ^5.1.4 => 5.1.4
```

I tried uninstalling && re installing sass loader but it didn't work for me

Also, I tried changing
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
to    = false;

and tried adding    devtool: isEnvProduction ? 'source-map' to webpack